# how to create a pattern for preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I tried googling this but I couldnt find anything clear about it. first I was hoping someone could help me write a pattern to get the info between these tags :

```
<vboxview leftinset="10" rightinset="0" stretchiness="1">    // CONTENT INSIDE HERE </vboxview>
```

and second, could you also please explain the pattern in details for each section and what it does and how you specify to get a certain part of the code.

Comment: Use an XML parser. Regexex are not designed for parsing XML or HTML.

Comment: ok, but then what are preg_match_all used for?? because on php.net they actually show examples where they parse html.

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi - Yes it's a bad example and they should change it. Regular expressions are for parsing data that has patterns in it. XML and HTML by definition are unstructured. You can use a regex to parse them but it's not a good idea because there's no requirement that the file be structured a certain way. In other words you run a high risk that your program will break even if someone gave you an XML file that matches your spec.

Comment: @Cfreak thanks for the useful info :) ... well I didnt know that...

Comment: Well, html does have patterns in it. It's just that they're not RELIABLE patterns.

Comment: You might want to have a look into PHPs XSLT functions, these are specifically made for modifying XML documents. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xslt.php

Comment: "Regular Expressions' are for parsing text with "regular patterns". Now that that is done with, many supposed "regular expression" implementations (.Net for sure, and I believe Perl, Python, PHP, and several other well known implementations) support syntax for matching _irregular_ patterns (particularly nested, synonymous HTML/XML tags, etc.) The only potential problem with what you appear to be doing is if there can be tags nested inside the `vboxView` element and even more so if there can be more `vboxView` elements nested inside as well. if not, there's absolutely no problem

Comment: @Cfreak: I'm seeing nightmares about "by definition unstructured".  That's incorrect on so many levels.  The problem is that the structure is more complex than regular expressions can cope with; regular languages can cope with context-free grammars, but XML and similar languages have a context-dependent grammar (basically, you can't handle arbitrarily nested tags with regular expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment on the question for my rant on SGML-based languages and regex...

Now to my answer.

If you know there will not be any other HTML/XML elements inside the tag in question, then this will work quite well:

```
<vboxview\s(?P<vboxviewAttributes>(\\>|[^>])*)>(?P<vboxviewContent>(\\<|[^<])*)</vboxview>
```

Broken down, this expression says:

```
<vboxview                  # match `<vboxview` literally
\s+                        # match at least one whitespace character
(?P<vboxviewAttributes>    # begin capture (into a group named "vboxViewAttributes")
   (\\>|[^>])*             #    any number of (either `\>` or NOT `>`)
)                          # end capture
>                          # match a `>` character
(?P<vboxviewContent>       # begin capture (into a group named "vboxViewContent")
   (\\<|[^<])*             #    any number of (either `\<` or NOT `<`)
)                          # end capture
</vboxview>                # match `</vboxview>` literally
```

You will need to escape and `>` characters inside the source as `\>` or even better as HTML/XML entities

If there are going to be nested constructs inside, then you are either going to [start running into problems with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), or you will have already decided to use another method that does not involve regex - either way is sufficient!

Comment: thanks alot :) ... I am looking for other methods, but for now this seems good

Answer (score 1):

As it has been mentioned in the comments it is usually not a good idea to try to extract things from HTML with regular expressions.  If you ever want to switch to a more bulletproof method here's a quick example of how you could easily extract the information using the [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) API.

```
<?php
function get_vboxview($html) {

    $output = array();

    // Create a new DOM object
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    // load a string in as html
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    // create a new Xpath object to query the document with
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    // an xpath query that looks for a vboxview node anywhere in the DOM
    // with an attribute named leftinset set to 10, an attribute named rightinset
    // set to 0 and an attribute named stretchiness set to 1
    $query = '//vboxview[@leftinset=10 and @rightinset=0 and @stretchiness=1]';

    // query the document
    $matches = $xpath->query($query);

    // loop through each matching node
    // and the textContent to the output
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
            $output[] = $m->textContent;
    }

    return $output;
}
?>
```

Better yet if there is guaranteed to be only one `vboxview` in your input (also assuming you have control of the HTML) you could add an `id` attribute to `vboxview` and cut the code down to a shorter and more generalized function.

```
<?php
function get_node_text($html, $id) {
    // Create a new DOM object
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    // load a string in as html
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    // return the textContent of the node with the id $id
    return $doc->getElementById($id)->textContent;
}
?>
```